# Change the default error message with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I don't manage to change the default error message from simple form, i tried to edit the simple form locale file but it seems to be ignored

Here is my locale file :

```
#config/locales/simple_form.en.yml
en:
  simple_form:
    error_notification:
      default_message: "A custom message:"
```

But i still get "Please review the problems below:"

Does anybody knows what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you restart the app after changing that file?

Comment: Weird. Works for me. I'm using simple_form 2.1.0.

Comment: A very late comment indeed. Use of tabs could also have caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `:default_message` to `:your_model_name`

As you can see [in the source](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/87323fd625802f3aea7fd7d8a2fd64016b18cdaa/lib/simple_form/error_notification.rb), `error_notification` method uses `translate_error_notification` to get translation from YAML file.

```
def translate_error_notification
  lookups = []
  lookups << :"#{object_name}"
  lookups << :default_message
  lookups << "Please review the problems below:"
  I18n.t(lookups.shift, scope: :"simple_form.error_notification", default: lookups)
end
```

For `user` model `lookups` contains:

```
lookups == [:user, :default_messge, "Please review the problems below:]
```

Translation could be differrent for each object so this transaction is called:

```
#config/locales/simple_form.en.yml
en:
  simple_form:
    error_notification:
      user: "A custom message:"
```

Vote if it'll help ;)